# understanding passportjs authenticate method

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am having an hard time understanding how passportjs authentication method works, in particular with the http-bearer strategy.

So I have two routes, one for registration and one for accessing user's profile, which goes through passportjs middleware. Have a look at the following code:

```
exports.register = function(req, res){
  User.schema.statics.generateUserToken(function(t){
    var user = new User({
      token: t,
      name: 'john doe',
    });

    user.save(function(e){
      res.json(user)
    });
  });
};
```

My authentication strategy is as follow:

```
var mongoose         = require('mongoose'),
    passport         = require('passport'),
    BearerStrategy   = require('passport-http-bearer').Strategy;

passport.use(new BearerStrategy(
  function(token, done) {
    User.findOne({ token: token }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user, { scope: 'read' });
    });
  }
));
```

as you can see, when a user requests the registration, my server returns him his object, with its token that should be locally saved.

Then, in a protected route, I added the passportjs middleware, like this:

```
app.get('/me', passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }), routes.me);
```

where I obviously get an unauthorized error. Why is this' where does passport.authenticate get the token from my client?! This is really confusing for me and is driving me mad. Any help?

Also, is this the right way of doing token authorization? Or do I also need some more details like timestamp, expires, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

could you please refer http-bearer's sample code: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-bearer/blob/master/examples/bearer/app.js to refactor your codebase. I think here is very clearly definition.